# ERROR ld: 9 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 - Making a dylib

Tags: c, macos, g++, dylib

`ld: 9 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64` is the final error I receive when I attempt to make a dylib on MacOS using these files -> main.c, subhook_unix.o, subhook_x86.o, subhook.o.

This is the command I used: g++ -dynamiclib -fPIC -o Gexecute.dylib subhook_unix.o subhook_x86.o subhook.o

Below is the returned error.

```
    subhook_x86.o
    subhook.o
duplicate symbol '_subhook_read_dst' in:
    subhook_x86.o
    subhook.o
duplicate symbol '_subhook_unprotect' in:
    subhook_unix.o
    subhook.o
duplicate symbol '_subhook_disasm' in:
    subhook_x86.o
    subhook.o
duplicate symbol '_subhook_install' in:
    subhook_x86.o
    subhook.o
duplicate symbol '_subhook_remove' in:
    subhook_x86.o
    subhook.o
duplicate symbol '_subhook_free' in:
    subhook_x86.o
    subhook.o
duplicate symbol '_subhook_free_code' in:
    subhook_unix.o
    subhook.o
duplicate symbol '_subhook_alloc_code' in:
    subhook_unix.o
    subhook.o
```

I predict that I have used either the incorrect command, or the code in the .o files has errors.

Comment: You have three different subhookXXX.o files, why?

Comment: @stark I am attempting to bind together the main.c code and https://github.com/Zeex/subhook to create a dylib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that you link three version of a same lib, of course there are same function or variable names among them. Try only link one of them.

Since linker said:

> duplicate symbol

"symbol" means function name or variable name, so "duplicate symbol" mean there are many same names in the files you are linking. By your error log those names look like function names, and those functions always appear in the other two .o file, so I made the conclusion that those three lib are the same one but different version.

Comment: Linking the code with one file did the trick!